# Difficulty using a mysql query in a for loop using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm having difficulty using a MySQL query in a for loop to produce an array of  IDs. Essentially, I have an array of parent IDs which I feed into the query via a for loop and am expecting to return an array of campaign IDs.

Inside the for loop I can echo every campaign ID for every parent ID but can't seem to access this array outside of the loop. I'm assuming this is a scoping issue, and I've fiddled with the code but aren't able to access an array of campaign_ids in its entirety outside of the loop.

My code is as follows:

```
$campaigns[] = array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($multIO); $i++) {

  $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT campaign_id
    FROM prod_appnexus.fact_network_analytics_feed_aggregated_364
    WHERE insertion_order_id = '.$multIO[$i]['IO_ID'].';';

  $retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval)) {
    $campaigns = $row['campaign_id'];
    echo print_r($campaigns);
  };
};
```

Does anybody know how I can troubleshoot this?

Any comments would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: A query in a loop is about the worst DB design you can have. Databases are there to avoid loops in your code, because the database is already handling that for you.

Comment: Yeah it's not ideal, I just can't think of an alternative way. Basically, I'm reading csv files every few hours that have a variable number of parent IDs and other parameters. If I didn't run a for loop I'd need to manually build a load of unions to retrieve campaign IDs etc.

Comment: No you don't, there is an "IN" function through which you can query multiple IDs at the same time.

Comment: The problem is that each parent ID has a parameter associated with it that I need each campaign ID in that parent ID to possess (this parameter varies and is pulled from the CSV). If i used an IN function every parent ID would share this same parameter, as would the campaign IDs. This is why I need to use a loop.

Comment: Yes, but you can split it up afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line with this:

```
$campaigns[] = $row['campaign_id'];
```

or:

```
$campaigns[$multIO[$i]['IO_ID']][] = $row['campaign_id'];
```

Comment: also change the first line with `$campaigns = array();` better :)

Comment: amazing thanks, I'm able to use the entirety of this array outside my loop now!

Answer (score 0):

Your sql is wrong dont use t1. when you are using single table and also when doing alias dont add as

```
$campaigns[] = array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($multIO); $i++) {

  $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT campaign_id
    FROM fact_network_analytics_feed_aggregated_364  T1
    WHERE insertion_order_id = '.$multIO[$i]['IO_ID'].';';

  $retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval)) {
    $campaigns = $row['campaign_id'];
    echo print_r($campaigns);
  };
};
```

Comment: sorry, I was trying to provide a minimal working example and must have cut off more than I expected.